# How to alter a API response with Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote this little app that takes in a set of starwars characters and returns images in an array.

```
const app = require('express')(); 
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const imageSearch = require('image-search-google');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
app.use(bodyParser.json())


const options = {page:1};


const getImages = (keywords) =>
 Promise.all(keywords.map(keyword => client.search(`${keyword} Wookieepedia`, options)))
 .then(data => firstResult = data.map(result => result[0].url)); 


 const fun = async () => {
     const res = await getImages(['yoda' , 'luke skywalker' , 'darth vader']);
     console.log(res);
 }

 fun()
```

The result of the above code looks like this :

```
[ 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Yoda_SWSB.png/revision/latest?cb=20150206140125',
  'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d9/Luke-rotjpromo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20091030151422',
  'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/a/a3/ANOVOS_Darth_Vader_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20150128225029' ]
```

But i would like a result where i can know which image belongs to which keyword.  Maybe a format like this or something similar :

```
[{<keyword> : <url>}]
```

I tried this :

```
const getImages = (keywords) =>
 Promise.all(keywords.map(keyword => {return { [keyword] : [client.search(`${keyword} Wookieepedia`, options)]}    } ))
 .then(data => firstResult = data.map(result => result)); 


 const fun = async () => {
     const res = await getImages(['yoda' , 'luke skywalker' , 'darth vader']);
     console.log(res);
 }

 fun()
```

Results were close but not good :

```
[ { yoda: [ [Promise] ] },
  { 'luke skywalker': [ [Promise] ] },
  { 'darth vader': [ [Promise] ] } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.search` returns a Promise. It can be awaited inside the mapping function if you make the mapping function async.

```js
const getImages = (keywords) =>
    Promise.all(keywords.map(async keyword => {
        return {[keyword]: await client.search(`${keyword} Wookieepedia`, options)}
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const getImages = (keywords) =>
 Promise.all(keywords.map(keyword => client.search(`${keyword} Wookieepedia`, options).then(result => [keyword, result])))
 .then(entries => Object.fromEntries(entries))
 .then(data => firstResult = data.map(result => result)); 

 const fun = async () => {
     const res = await getImages(['yoda' , 'luke skywalker' , 'darth vader']);
     console.log(res);
 }

 fun()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `async` you could add a `then` clause to the search promise that combines the keyword value with the result array - or with the first result as shown:

```
const getImages = keywords => Promise.all(
     keywords.map( keyword =>
         client.search(`${keyword} Wookieepedia`, options)
        .then( result => ( {[keyword]: result[0]} ))
     )
)
```